# Replace multiple value in SPARQL

Tags: sparql

I'm trying to use the BIND and REPLACE functions to create a new column in which there is the real title of an object code.

For example, I have a column with ENV_TOB and I would like to create a column that changes "ENV_TOB" to "SLIDE".  I have several codes like "ENV_XXX" that I would also like to include in my query. So far, I've only managed to replace one value.

```
select ?code_type

{

     GRAPH xxx:optimized {
        
        OPTIONAL {?o xxx:code_type ?code_type}
              
     FILTER (?code_type IN
      ("ENV_BAL"^^xsd:string, "ENV_BBF"^^xsd:string, "ENV_CAB"^^xsd:string, "ENV_JRG"^^xsd:string, "ENV_STO"^^xsd:string, "ENV_TJE"^^xsd:string,  "ENV_TOB"^^xsd:string,  "ENV_TPP"^^xsd:string ))
      }
   
   BIND (REPLACE(?code_type, "ENV_TOB", "Slide") AS ?TYPE_JEU)  
  
}
```

Comment: not sure if I understand, can you share data and expected result please? Also, `REPLACE` takes a regex pattern which means you could easily use this to provide alternative tokens with the corresponding regex operator

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to get a different value occurs in the data, and the mapping a direct mapping, that is, if you want "Slide" when the value is exactly "ENV_TOB", you can use a VALUES block.  For instance:

```
@prefix : <urn:ex:>

:a :label "ENV_TOB" .
:b :label "ENV_TOB" .
:c :label "ENV_BBF" .
:d :label "ENV_CAB" .
:e :label "Other Label" .
:f :label "I went down the ENV_TOB" .
:g :label "I live in a ENV_CAB" .
```

```
prefix : <urn:ex:>

select ?subject ?label ?better_label where {

        ?subject :label ?label .

        optional {
                values (?label ?better_label) {
                        ("ENV_TOB" "Slide")
                        ("ENV_CAB" "House")
                }
        }
}
```

| subject | label | better_label |
| --- | --- | --- |
| :a | "ENV_TOB" | "Slide" |
| :b | "ENV_TOB" | "Slide" |
| :c | "ENV_BBF" |  |
| :d | "ENV_CAB" | "House" |
| :e | "Other Label" |  |
| :f | "I went down the ENV_TOB" |  |
| :g | "I live in a ENV_CAB" |  |